# Run php script on background in PHP with nohup CLI

Tags: background, ssh, command-line-interface, php

I,m trying to run one php script in background. But its no working... I can only run directly from the ssh terminal. Using the same cli script.

On the terminal, first i access the path: `cd labs.lung.com.br/ztbot/bin/v2/php` 
After that, i run my script in background: `nohup php get_tweets.php > /dev/null &`

And it works! But, when i try to do the same thing with my php script: `exec("nohup php get_tweets.php > /dev/null &");` doesnt work. Both files are in the same directory.

I list the files in that folder: `exec("ls");` And they are in the same level...

Until PID its returned, when i run: `echo(shell_exec("nohup php get_tweets.php > /dev/null & echo $!"));`

But for some reason the script doesnt run.

Comment: Have you tried capturing/logging the standard output / standard error output from the shell execution?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my poor knowledge, how i do that?

Comment: I solved! Fosco tell me to get the error output and got it! Stupid bug.. i was trying to access one file off other directory. Sorry guys! Thanks for help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the absolute path to php.

```
    echo(shell_exec("nohup /usr/bin/php get_tweets.php > /dev/null & echo $!"));
```

Comment: Only returns the PID (http://labs.lung.com.br/ztbot/bin/v2/php/sistema.php), but the process doesnt run.

Comment: Can you post the output of the following code: `$cmd = 'set';
echo "<pre>".shell_exec($cmd)."</pre>";`

Comment: Cool!  Glad you figured it out! :)