# PHP script wait for previous one to finish

Tags: php, parallel-processing, wait, shell-exec, nohup

I have this example script:

```
<?php
    $time = time();
    shell_exec('nohup sleep 30 2>/tmp/test >/tmp/test &');
    $time2 = time();
    echo $time2 - $time;
?>
```

when I run it for the first time it show immediately 0 , but when I run it for the second time it wait for the sleep command to finish the it shows the 0.
what should i do to make it run immediately without waiting for the sleep command ?

Comment: I would guess that the file is locked. So if you want to run it multiple times simultaneously, you should use different / random file names.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100872/run-php-script-on-background-in-php-with-nohup-cli

Comment: Do you want to do a "sleep" command or a "background" command?